# Processing was halted because there were too many errors

Tags: software-installation

Getting this error installing anything, any help would be appreciated.

```
e@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                     
Hit:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease             
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease              
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease           
Hit:7 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security InRelease        
Hit:8 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-updates InRelease         
Get:9 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-security InRelease [7,453 B]
Hit:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:11 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-updates InRelease [7,452 B]
Hit:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease 
Hit:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/heyarje/makemkv-beta/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:14 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/stellarium/stellarium-releases/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:15 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Fetched 14.9 kB in 3s (4,865 B/s)                           
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

e@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libappstream-glib8 libfuse2 libwireshark15 libwiretap12 libwsutil13
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  gjs libgjs0g
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/13.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-32-generic (6.2.0-32.32~22.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-32-generic (6.2.0-32.32~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-32-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-32-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 10: /etc/default/grub: snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0: no
t found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-32-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-32-generic package post-installation script subpro
cess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.2.0-32-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

https://pastebin.com/W4HYMFd3

Comment: Line 10 of `/etc/default/grub` contains `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` and that option is not valid.

Comment: Im new at this, what do I need to do about this?

Comment: Edit the file: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`, and correct or uncomment line 10. Then save (Ctrl + O) and exit the program (Ctrl + X). then do `sudo update-grub`.